# Magento order email template and subtotal

Tags: magento, email, subtotal

I do not want the subtotal is  in order email template. where can I change that?

magento 1.7

thank you

Comment: Please show your current effort to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

this code comming in below file....

just go to the template file checkout/cart/totals.phtml

```
    <?php echo $this->renderTotals(); ?>
```

located into tbody.

i think this one help you...

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the `sales_email_order_items` handle under layout/sales.xml  you will get the answer.

and try to use your efforts also.